# Refresh textview when thread is sleeping

Tags: android

I want to display some text for a few seconds and then quit my application for that i use the following code:

```
public void idonot(View V) throws InterruptedException
{
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TEXT_VIEW);
    txt.setText("Please uninstall application");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

The problem is the textView is not getting refreshed what can i do ?

Comment: What do you mean with not getting refreshed? Will the text "Please uninstall application" not appear? Is this a new thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android UI runs on the main thread. Which means, the UI is also drawn on the main thread. If you put the main thread to sleep and then kill it (!), how will the UI get refreshed?

Instead use a `Handler` to post a task to execute after a delay. This runnable will be posted to the thread's message queue and will be executed after 2 seconds.

```
public void idonot(View V)
{
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TEXT_VIEW);
    txt.setText("Please uninstall application");

    (new Handler()).postDelayed((new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();
        }
    }), 2000);
}
```